# Margin white-space

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margin

I was modifying a page and out of no where white-space started showing on it. It is making the page wider than 100% width in my mobile media query (anything from `640px` down. It looks like this:

[image]

The only thing I changed in my main desktop view is:

```
 #see-all-services-text {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    position: relative;
    left: -30%;
}
```

I changed `left: -30%;` from `left: -20%;`

and then I widened the `blue-text` area within my main desktop view as well.

The thing is within the developer inspect tool, I do not see anything that is showing exceeding the 100% width. Sorry for this being a pretty broad question. I just don't see the area in which is causing this to be able to fix it, so any insight of something I over-looked would be amazing.

Comment: Reduce the font size to 1em

Comment: @ArifBurhan For what? Why would that be making the width more than 100%?

Comment: I only can reproduce it if I scroll horizontally. To avoid this, at least in my computer, yo ucan make a `body { overflow-x: hidden }` to avoid the horizontal overflow. And I'm glad to see you again `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have child elements animating in and out of the `.blue` wrapper, it pushes element width further than the body. You can fix this by adding

```
.blue {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So the starting point for them does this or the ending point? I don't get it.

Comment: Both. You can see the horizontal scrollbar adjusting when you first load the page, and then it stops at the end wherever the end point is for the child elements.

Comment: I just don't get why that would cause white space on the right when the containers are within the blue element and are centered within it. Your solution worked...I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: I think its probably due to the .`hand-wrap img` having a width of 500px.